# Affidavit for emergency travel document for Pakistan

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports, paperwork, pakistani-citizens

If a person has to travel to Pakistan urgently from UK having expired passport, there is one of the requirements to provide Affidavit stating:

> 1. When applicant last entered the UK
> 2. In which visa category he / she was granted the entry
> 3. Explanation of circumstance of his / her overstay, in case applicant has remained in the UK after expiry of his / her visa
> 4. That there is no case pending with Home Office OR Police. IF applicant has a pending case with Home Office he /she needs to produce one of the followings:
> 5. A copy of Home Office Letter showing Case Reference number
>      Home Office letter of refusal

From where he/she can get this Affidavit to get emergency travel document?
I got this requirements on this site
http://www.phclondon.org/consular/traveldocument/

Answer (score 4):

An affidavit is a formal legal statement, taken under oath and witnessed by a legal official such as a Notary public. [You can find more information here](http://findlaw.co.uk/law/government/other_law_and_government_topics/500584.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is no template for this; you can go to the Embassy and the staff there can write this up for you (in Urdu, if you are not well versed). You can also submit it in, but you have to:

1. Write it up on a piece of paper - address it to the Counselor [insert the Embassy's address]
2. You need to sign it in front of an officer from the Embassy (otherwise its not an affadavit); or get it stamped/witnessed by a Notary (like a judge/police officer, etc.) - its just easier to get it stamped at the Embassy. If you get it written at the embassy, they will write it on a piece of paper with the embassy letterhead.